# Inject a property (recursively) without passing it as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I'm trying to achieve maybe something that might be impossible.

We have a big MVC 5 application. I created a small MVC project to simulate and explain what I want to apply into that big MVC project.

I have a controller that has unique Id. In this sample project the unique Id is regenerated for each request. In the MVC project, it is a bit more complex and different. However it's not relevant in the scope of this example.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public string UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var worker = new WorkerA();
        worker.DoWork();
        return View();
    }
}
```

The `FooController` creates `WorkerA` which creates `WorkerB` which creates `WorkerC` and so on. The workers are not the same. They don't have the same interface/implementation. To make the example simple I made them look similar.

Here's the Workers:

```
public class WorkerA
{
    public string UniqueId = string.Empty;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var worker = new WorkerB();
        worker.DoWork();
        //...
        //...

    }
}
public class WorkerB
{
    public string UniqueId = string.Empty;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var worker = new WorkerC();
        worker.DoWork();
    }
}
```

I want to have inject the property `UniqueId` into the worker without having to passing it as a parameter.

I want to avoid having to do this:

```
public WorkerA(string uniqueId)
{
    UniqueId = uniqueId;
}
```

But I need to do the same for all the other workers.

**EDIT**

Is there a way to acheive that with ninject?

Comment: can you not set it as a property during initialisation? like this `var worker = new WorkerA() { UniqueId = uniqueId } `

Comment: Is the uniqueId for the Worker classes the same as the original UniqueID for the "parent" FooController class. Or are all UniqueIds unique?

Comment: I've never seen a requirement to not be able to pass a parameter before so i'm not sure what your exact situation is but couldn't you just create a singleton GUIDManager class with an ActiveGuid property and set it internally on the children with that?

Comment: why do you not want to pass the variable?

Comment: Injecting the value to each `Worker` is much more sensible than having to rely on contextual data (like thread / http-context)

Comment: I need to do something more like `Radu Olteanu`'s answer.

Comment: @DaveBecker: that's the point of my question! I don't want to always pass it.

Comment: @billybob I don't think the point of your question is clear. It's unclear whether you want to have the same id for all workers in the requests. It's unclear whether there should be uninitalized (un-injected) id's, too.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit: I want the same Id for every class that is called from a parent and that has the same property name. So the Id of the parent class should be injected in the child class without passing it as a parameter.

Comment: @billybob please update the question and example accordingly. We can't expect everyone coming to have a look at this question in a years time to read all the comments. And futures readers should be able to profit from the Q&A here, too.

Comment: @billybob are the workers really `new`'ed up by their parents or are the instanciated by ninject? If you're newing objects up then an IoC container does not know about their existence and cannot inject something into them unless you tell the kernel to (by doing `kernel.Inject(worker)`).

Comment: However, knowledge of the kernel is a bad thing - should be kept to the composition root (google it). So this seems a typical case for an [abstract factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/), or, to save some typing work: [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using Microsoft.Practices.Unity in the following manner:

```
 public class WorkerA
    {
        [Dependency]
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }

    }

    public class WorkerB
    {
        [Dependency]
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    }
```

And after that :

```
 var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<WorkerA>(new InjectionProperty(nameof(WorkerA.UniqueId),"WorkerAValue"));
            container.RegisterType<WorkerA>(new InjectionProperty(nameof(WorkerB.UniqueId), "WorkerBValue"));
```

Later, you can request the instances from the container with the desired properties configured:

```
var workerA = container.Resolve<WorkerA>();
var workerB = container.Resolve<WorkerB>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
worker.GetType().GetField("prop")?.SetValue(worker, "guid");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a singleton class to manage the GUID and deliver it to the child classes that way. This way you can still do it in a constructor but not have to pass it as a parameter

```
public class GUIDManager
{

    private static GUIDManager _instance;
    private Guid _activeGuid;

    public Guid ActiveGuid {
        get { return _activeGuid; }
        set { _activeGuid = value; }

    }

    private GUIDManager()
    {
        if (_activeGuid == null)
            _activeGuid = new Guid();
    }

    public static GUIDManager GetInstance()
    {

        if(_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new GUIDManager();
        }

        return _instance;
    }

}

public class WorkerB
{

    public string UniqueId = string.Empty;

    public WorkerB()
    {
        var manager = GUIDManager.GetInstance();
        UniqueId = manager.ActiveGuid.ToString();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var worker = new WorkerC();
        worker.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already thought about that solution, However, I prefer to use an injection for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your question i'm not entirely clear about all the workers in the same request getting the same ID or not. If they all should get the same ID then it's simple:

Wrap the ID in a class and use `InRequestScope()`:

```
public class BrowserTabId 
{
    public string browserTabId;
    public BrowserTabId(string tabId)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tabId))
        {
            throw new NullArgumentException();
        }
        this.browserTabId = tabId;
    }

    public string Id { get { return this.browserTabId; } }
}

Bind<BrowserTabId>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => 
        new BrowserTabId(HttpContext.Items["BrowserTabId"] as string)))
    .InRequestScope();
```

For testability reasons you can also slap on an interface `IUniqueRequestId` and create the binding for that.

This will result in all workers / objects created during the same request receiveing the same `BrowserTabId`. If you don't want to use c-tor injection you **can use property injection instead**. If you don't want to inject the value all the type, then use a `When(..)` condition to specify when to inject and when not to. Combine this with the [null-object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to keep ninject from complaining that it can't inject a requested type.

### Property Injection

Adapt a worker as follows:

```
public class WorkerA
{
    [Inject]
    public BrowserTabId BrowserTabId { get; set; }

    ....
 }
```

Note, however, for this to work, like normal constructor injection, it is necessary that either the `WorkerA` is instanciated by ninject or that Ninject is informed about its existence by `Ninject.Inject(workerAInstance)`

### Scoping

Since you mention that the lifetime of the ID in your actual application is somewhat more complicated, I guess you will have to use something different than `InRequestScope` - maybe roll your own scope (by using `InScope(...)`). Or Maybe, `InCallScope()` is as viable alternative. However, without knowing what exactly it is what you need, it's a bit difficult to advise you properly.

Comment: In fact, in the main application, we have an `AuthorizeAttribute`. In that attribute, we retrieve a unique Id (specific to the user tab). Later, I want to work with that `browserTabId` and combine it with the `sessionId`. I have lot (thousands) of class that all receives the `sessionId` right now. I want to avoid doing that since the only parameters that they have is going to be `sessionId` and `browserTabId`. Can you give me a concrete example how to use it, please.

Comment: BTW, the `browserTabId` is injected in the controller in `OnActionExecuting` function. I get it like that: `_browserTabId = HttpContext.Items["BrowserTabId"] as string;`